# Spring Rest Hibernate Update List with PUT method

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest

I'm tying to update List with a rest service, but an InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException is thrown :

```
Parameter value element [Sharing{uuid=af777b47-3dfc...updated=2016-05-04T10:37:29.000Z}]  did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateChecked", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public int update(@RequestBody SharingList shares){
    return this.sharingService.updateChecked(shares);
}
```

Service :

```
public int updateChecked(SharingList shares) {
        int updated = sharingDao.setCheckedSharingFor(shares);
        return updated;
    }
```

DAO :

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Sharing s SET s.checked=1 WHERE uuid in :shares")
int setCheckedSharingFor(@Param("shares") SharingList shares);
```

SharingList:

```
public class SharingList extends ArrayList<Sharing> {
```

}

What is wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the answer here

```
Sharing{uuid=af777b47-3dfc...updated=2016-05-04T10:37:29.000Z}]  
did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]
```

Hibernate doesn't have artificial intelligence to understand that it should get  `uuid` from `Sharing`.

Fo this query

```
@Query("UPDATE Sharing s SET s.checked=1 WHERE uuid in :shares")
```

you should provide a collection of `UUID` as the `shares` parameter.